# how to set the download path in php

Tags: laravel-5.3

I'm a web developer.

DownloadController.php

```
$local_file = 'file.zip';
$download_file = 'd:\temp\download.zip';
if(file_exists($local_file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($local_file).'"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($local_file));
    readfile($download_file);
}
```

I hope download the 'file.zip' and downloaded path that 'd:\temp\download.zip'

Anyone help me!
Thank u.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following code to download a file:

```
return response()->download($pathToFile);
```

OR

```
return response()->download($pathToFile, $name, $headers)
```

> The `download` method may be used to generate a response that forces the user's browser to `download` the file at the given path. The download method accepts a file name as the second argument to the method, which will determine the file name that is seen by the user downloading the file. Finally, you may pass an array of HTTP headers as the third argument to the method:

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/responses#file-downloads)